# email server with catch-all similar to gmail

Tags: linux, windows-server, smtp

I am looking for an e-mail server that can replicate the [gmail plus addressing](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Plus-Addressing-in-Gmail), however I would like to be able to replace the + with another character (_ or -) due to some [plus haters](http://mozilla.wikia.com/wiki/User:Me_at_work/plushaters)

I would prefer a free solution that works on Linux, however I would be open to windows (server) and paid* solutions as well.

I would also add the requirements of IMAP and secure connections, but I hope that those are standard for any e-mail server by now.

*Paid solutions should be less than $50/yr, since at that price I would simply go to Google Apps and [configure it like this](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/automatic-disposable-email-addresses-for-google-apps-611.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/):

- free and open source
- Linux/Mac
- support [plus-addressing](https://superuser.com/q/587458/116475): in your /etc/postfix/main.cfg file, add the line `recipient_delimiter = +`. More generally, it supports [sub-addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) (term used by the [RFC 5233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233)) aka. address tags, i.e. you can change the `+` with another character.